# Fading animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to do fading animation in android. By clicking an image transition takes place, and I can see next image.

But how to move back to first image by clicking second image?

```
public void fade (View view) {
    ImageView naruto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.naruto);
    ImageView sasuke = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sasuke);
    naruto.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
    sasuke.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
}

public void reappear (View view) {
    ImageView sasuke1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sasuke);
    ImageView naruto1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.naruto);
    sasuke1.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
    naruto1.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fade:

```
public void fade (View view) {
    ImageView naruto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.naruto);
    ImageView sasuke = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sasuke);
    naruto.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            naruto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    sasuke.setAlpha(0f);
    sasuke.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    sasuke.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000).setListener(null);
}
```

Reappear:

```
public void reappear (View view) {
    ImageView sasuke = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sasuke);
    ImageView naruto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.naruto);
    sasuke.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            naruto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    naruto.setAlpha(0f);
    naruto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    naruto.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
}
```

Comment: No need for AnimatorListenerAdapter or AnimatorListener when dealing with ViewPropertyAnimators. Instead you can use: `sasuke.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        sasuke.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });`